# Image of $\frac{2x}{\ln(x)}$

Tags: limits, analysis, functions, logarithms, asymptotics

I'm trying to calculate the image of $f(x)=\frac{2x}{\ln(x)}$. I tried to find the horizontal asymptotes. But I couldn't. the $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x)$  is $\infty$. I also tried to find the oblique one but I couldn't.

I have no clue.

Comment: What happens as $x\to 1^\pm$?  And what happens at $x\to 0^+$?

Comment: Does the numerator increase faster or slower than the denominator? after the pole at $1$, is it generally going to increase or decrease?

Answer (score 1):

For $x \in [0,1)$ the function $\frac{2x}{\ln{x}}$ will range from $0 \text{  to } -\infty$, this is because there is an asymptote at $x=1$ and our function is negative and decreasing in that range (with a max value of $0$ at $x=0$).

For $x \in (1,\infty)$ the function $\frac{2x}{\ln{x}}$ is always positive, has a positive second derivative, a vertical asymptote at $x=1$ and goes to infinity as $x$ grows large. That means there is only extrema point which must be a minimum in this range. We can find that to be at $x= e$ where the minimum value of the function is $\frac{2e}{\ln{e}}=2e$. So we know in the domain $x \in (1,\infty)$ our function ranges over $[2e, \infty)$.

Since those two domains cover the entire valid domain of our function we can say its range is given by

$$(-\infty,0] \cup [2e,\infty)=\mathbb{R} \setminus (0,2e) .$$

Comment: singular form of *extrema* is *extremum*

Comment: 0 is not in the domain of the function.

Comment: Oh thanks! Now I understood